# Aggregate XML blocks in different files

Tags: apache-camel

I have an XML file with a set of entries:

```
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
      <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
      <City>Mill Valley</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>10999</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
      <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
        <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
        <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
      </Item>
  </PurchaseOrder>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99505" OrderDate="1999-10-22">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Cristian Osorio</Name>
      <Street>456 Main Street</Street>
      <City>Buffalo</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>UK</Country>
    </Address>
        <Item PartNumber="456-NM">
        <ProductName>Power Supply</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>45.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
  </PurchaseOrder>
```

My aim is to group all orders in different files for each country. So for example, all US orders in a file us.xml.
I have arranged for the following Aggregation Strategy

```
<aggregate strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy"
        completionSize="10" completionTimeout="500">
        <correlationExpression>
             <xpath>/PurchaseOrder/Address/Country/text()</xpath>
        </correlationExpression>
         <to uri="file:/home/data/other?fileName=orders.xml" />
</aggregate>
```

However I don't know how to specify a filename for each group (as it is only the last group of entries gets written in the file orders.xml).
Any help ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the `<Country>` from the XML payload and store as header on the exchange, for example in the aggregation strategy, or before calling the aggregator, you can use `setHeader`:

```
<setHeader name="country">
  <xpath>PurchaseOrder/Address/Country/text()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

The you can use that to know if its US, UK or what country it is, and therefore also compute a file name you need.

```
fileName=orders-${header.country}.xml
```

And PS mind about streaming: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

And btw if you write to the same file name then Camel will by default override the file, you can configure it to append instead using `fileExist=Append`. See more details in the docs: http://camel.apache.org/file2